# Estimate of original value in a table rounded at the nearest multiple of 5

Tags: estimation, missing-data, tables

Let's assume that there exist a table ("Table A") with several rows and columns.
Each cell of the last column shows the sum of all values of the respective row, each cell of the last row the sum of all values of the respective column.

Let's make an example to be clear. The actual tables I have are of 19 rows and 7 columns (or similar size), therefore I need a solution working with bigger tables.

| row | a | b | c (sum) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 6 | 7 | 13 |
| r2 | 16 | 12 | 28 |
| r3 | 19 | 24 | 43 |
| r4 (sum) | 41 | 43 | 84 |

Now, let's assume all values are published in table B, but rounded to the nearest multiple of 5.

| row | a | b | c (rounded sum of original values | d (sum of rounded values) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | 5 | 5 | 15 | 10 |
| r2 | 15 | 10 | 30 | 25 |
| r3 | 20 | 25 | 45 | 45 |
| r4 (rounded sum of original values) | 40 | 45 | 85 | 85 |
| r5 (sum of rounded values) | 40 | 40 | 90 | - |

Now the rounded sums of the original values and the sum of the rounded values may differ. In general, the rounded sum of the original values should be nearer to the true value than the sum of the rounded value.

I have only table B, and I want to make an estimate of the values of table A.
I want to exploit the fact that the true values are integers which deviate at the highest 2 units from the rounded value, and that the rounded total sum in cell (r4,c), i.e. 85 in the example, is probably the best guess of the total sum  (I remind that I am working with tables that are about 19x7, therefore it is not simple to make a better guess).

| row | a | b | c (sum) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | x11 | x12 | x11+x12 |
| r2 | x21 | x22 | x21+x22 |
| r3 | x31 | x32 | x31+x32 |
| r4 (sum) | x11+x21+x31 | x12+x22+x23 | 85? |

I suppose that a kind of algorithm for doing this must exist, but I have no idea of how it may be called. Actually I have no idea at all on how to approach the problem.

To calculate thee values I can use R, but if it were possible to do it in excel it would be better. I would be grateful for any suggestion on where to search the solution of the problem, or the name of this kind of problems.

Comment: +1 -- this is an interesting, well-formulated question.  Closely related (although not an answer) is my post about a comparable rounding problem at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/521718/919 and another one at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/331278/919.  A different approach to solving this problem would apply Bayesian techniques by adopting a prior distribution for the table entries.  Empirical Bayes might work very well here.